# How to trigger a Dialog from an Application instance?

Tags: exception, dialog, android

i'm looking for a way to show a Dialog no matter what activity is shown.

I think what I'm trying to achieve is better explained using some code :

```
public class MyApp extends Application {

        public MyApplication() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
                super.onCreate();

                boolean success = doSomeWebServiceCall();

                if (!success)
                        showAlertDialog();  // fails with error
        }
}
```

The error I am getting is :

```
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(375): Caused by: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
at android.view.ViewRoot.setView(ViewRoot.java:460)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only an `Activity` can display a `Dialog`. Consider using a dialog-themed `Activity` instead, which can be launched from your `Application` object via `startActivity()`.

Comment: what context do you give to startActivity?

Comment: @David: The `Application` is a `Context`.

Comment: works using intent.setFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK );

Answer (score 2):

I think a toast (could even throw in an image in this toast) is much more convenient if you don't need user interaction

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "YOUR TEXT HERE", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
LinearLayout toastView = (LinearLayout) toast.getView();
ImageView infoImage = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
infoImage.setImageResource(drawable.your_image);
toastView.addView(infoImage, 0);
toast.show();
```

Comment: That's interesting to see you can do that with a toast! But I want to make sure the user sees the dialog/toast. Is there a way to prevent the toast to disappear automatically?

Comment: @David: No, sorry, a `Toast` has to automatically go away, as it normally does not respond to user input.